# Swift User Location Issue

Tags: ios, swift

I had working mapview on users location at the start of my project but now it wont zoom in on the user at startup. Any idea how to fix this? the code i use:

In Class

```
  class MapViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate

  var Locationmanager = CLLocationManager()
```

In viewdidload

```
    self.Locationmanager.delegate = self
    self.Locationmanager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    self.Locationmanager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    self.Locationmanager.startUpdatingLocation()
    self.Mapview.showsUserLocation = true
    Mapview.setCenterCoordinate(Mapview.userLocation.coordinate, animated: true)
```

In function

```
      func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[MKUserLocation]) {

      let latitude = Locationmanager.location?.coordinate.latitude
      let longitude = Locationmanager.location?.coordinate.longitude
      let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D (latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)
      let region = MKCoordinateRegion (center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan (latitudeDelta: 0.02, longitudeDelta: 0.02))
      self.Mapview.setRegion(region, animated: true)
      self.Locationmanager.stopUpdatingLocation()
```

And in info.plist

```
      NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to make a map view display the user's location, there is no need, and no point, to tell the location manager to do anything. Get rid of all that code - it is actually doing you harm here. Just set the map view's `userTrackingMode` to `.follow` and stand back.

Comment: Well, i need to ask permission for the users location.. will try and remove and see what happends

Comment: Nope didn't resolve it.. any other code for finding users location?

Comment: Thanks, helped me out alot! (Y)